# Doxygen only reading comments from begining of file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, doxygen

I am trying to document some MATLAB code using Doxygen, but it is only reading comments from the top of the file. I am using this github repo for converting the MATLAB to be readable by doxygen: https://github.com/simgunz/doxymatlab.

I would like to create sections of documentation mixed in with sections of code to explain how the code works and the equations it is based off of. Does anyone know how to do this? It appears that Doxygen is normally able to do this, so I am not sure if I have done something wrong setting up Doxygen in my project or if the matlab parser I am using prevents this.

```
%>@file file_name.m
%>@brief file description
%>
%>Doxygen picks up this comment
%>
*Some MATLAB code*
%>Doxygen does not read this comment
```

Thanks for the help.